# What happen if a systemd service reach its MemoryLimit?

Tags: systemd, coreos

Does systemd restart the service or the system just refuse to let the service allocate more memory?

Comment: Also, it would be nice to know how the service memory being calculated for a service. Say the service ExecStart a bash that spawn several other commands inside itself and then do a tail, does it sum up all running processed spawned by the bash? What if the ExecStart starts a docker container, does it sum up all running process inside docker container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `MemoryLimit` just causes `systemd` to run the service in a [cgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) with the configured memory limit. It's up to the service to decide how to handle resource exhaustion.